MSVC allows void functions to return a value (Compiler Warning C4098) yet clang does not
I have the following C code, which returns a value from a void function.
void foo() {
    // do something
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}

I expect this code to fail compilation and Clang fails with an error. However, MSVC allows this with a warning: warning C4098: 'foo': 'void' function returning a value
I would like Clang to behave as MSVC does. Is there a way to configure Clang such that it will also allow this? I've tried clang-cl and the flag -fms-compatibility to no avail.

Out of curiosity: why do you want to have a void function returning a value ? It doesn't sound like a good idea anyway.

gcc before 14 also gives a warning instead of an error for this.

@wohlstad it's a snippet provided by a student taking a c language course. The snippet is intended to illustrate a compiler's strange behavior. Of course it's a bad idea.

However, if you try to use the supposed value returned with int i = foo(); then MSVC does create an error.

@WeatherVane good point, as there's no way to compile this expression.

-Wno-return-type ?

Re “Clearly this should not compile”: That is not clear. Nothing in the C standard requires an implementation to reject an “invalid program” generally (the #error directive must cause rejection), and note 9 at 5.1.1.3 1 says an implementation “can also successfully translate an invalid program.”

In general, the standard rarely requires implementations to reject invalid programs. Such a requirement makes it hard to provide implementation-dependent extensions. That's why these types of things are usually reported as warnings, not fatal errors.

@EricPostpischil , Barmar -
Thank you for explaining this. I've edited my question to match.

@freestyle it will disable the warning too

Why no just change the erroneous return 0; to return; since you want to keep the return in the code? At least then it would be correct C

@JohnH Because the purpose here is not to get legal C language code but to understand why different compilers behave differently when compiling the same malformed code, and how that difference may be avoided.
If two compilers were generating semantically different binaries for well-formed code than there wouldn't have been any mystery. It would have simply meant that at least one compiler has a bug.

You expect it to fail but you want it to be allowed. Don't you trust your own expectations? Avoid malformed code. That should solve all problems.

It is quite easy.
Add to your command line -Wno-error=return-type
Example: https://godbolt.org/z/P4vePWEcT
It will not treat this warning as an error.
